# Tibco error on Parasoft soa test tool

Tags: unit-testing, csv, automated-tests, tibco

Im using Parasoft SOA test tool and I get the error : Failed to open Tibrv in native implementation while running my tests using TIBCO. I have added the jar file in the soa classpath and also in the environment variables. can some one please help

Answer (score 1):

This error says that the RV client can't link the native Rendezvous libraries.
So adding the jar file is only half of the job. It might help to know more what you like to do and in what way you start "TIBCO" (there are many TIBCO products) to help on this issue.

Generally on windows platforms the RV dll's should be in your Path Variable.

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the dlls that I have to add in the path variable

Comment: @user3303707 add <TIBCO_HOME>\tibrv\<version>\bin to your PATH. e.g. C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin